# How can you tell when a dom node gets added to the document?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there any good way to get alerted when a dom node is added to the document? If you're putting together dom nodes in javascript, usually you put them together leaves-first, so that you're not reflowing all the time. But this means that when elements are added, they aren't visible on the page, which means certain information about them is inaccessible/wrong. For example `offsetWidth` will be 0 before its added to the document's flow, regardless of its width after its added.

So I would ideally like some way to get an event when a node is added to the document so I can then do things that require `offsetWidth` and other things like that that require it to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Using a mutation observer to observe `document` should be a reasonable tool to use in most cases (it might not be reasonable if you're setting up a listener intended to listen for a long period of time):

```
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                if(mutation.target.contains(block.domNode)) {
                    // do your thing, then..
                    observer.disconnect()
                }
            })
        })
        observer2.observe(document, {childList: true, subtree: true})
```

Note that if the dom node is removed from the document, then reinserted, the above code will not catch that (but could be modified to).

Comment: Keep in mind that Mutation Observers have very limited functionality, if any, in IE and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver

Comment: Looks like mutation observer is there for the latest version of all major browsers at this point actually. But yes, supporting versions of IE older  than 11 would require something else.

Comment: You're correct. I should have been more specific. I always try to go, at the minimum, 1 generation back with IE. That being said, I suppose in this situation, it's one of those times where you have to throw up your hands and say  "what can you do?"